# Conditional column choosing sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure that receives many `parameterIds` and I want to choose a value from another table columns according to the `parameterIds` inputted. So the tables look like this.

**Parameters table**

```
ParameterID 
33
34
35
```

**Values Table**

```
InstallID       33Value      34Value   35Value
```

How can I retrieve the values according to the parameters inputted?

Comment: Use dynamic pivot http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns/

Comment: How are you passing in multiple parameters?

Comment: @GordonLinoff As a comma separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN @ParameterID = 33 THEN (SELECT 33Value
                                      FROM   [Values Table])
         WHEN @ParameterID = 34 THEN (SELECT 34Value
                                      FROM   [Values Table])
         ELSE (SELECT 35Value
               FROM   [Values Table])
       END
```